# Use VBS to run PowerShell

Tags: vbscript, powershell-2.0

So I have a .ps1 file which creates a form.
That Form takes 10-20secs depending on PCs performance and connection on first load.

Now I am currently using VBS to load a simple .gif file as a loading screen concurrently running the .ps1 file right after.
My issue at the moment is that, I want to close the loading screen when the form pops up. I tried to determine via processes but that failed because of the it loads powershell.exe but the form takes 10sec...
Is it this possible?
Of have you guys got a better idea to do this?

```html
Dim i
Dim strComputer
Dim FindProc
Dim counter 
counter = 0
strComputer = "."
FindProc = "powershell.exe"
'Load the gif file
Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With objExplorer
    .Navigate "about:blank"
    .Visible = 1
    .Document.Title = "Show Image"
    .Toolbar=False
    .Statusbar=False
    .Top=400
    .Left=400
    .Height=355
    .Width=435
    .Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<img src='\\10.10.67.173\Templates$\Scripts\Resources\loadingtest.gif'>"
End With

'Run the PS script
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
objShell.Run "CMD /C START /B " & objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%SystemRoot%") & "\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file \\10.10.67.173\Templates$\Scripts\FormSignature-V0.9.5.ps1", 0, False



'Determine when to close Loading screen
Do While counter < 3
 wscript.Sleep 2000
 
 Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
  & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
 Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
  ("Select Name from Win32_Process WHERE Name LIKE '" & FindProc & "%'")
 If colProcessList.count>0 then
  'Quit the process if it finds its running
  WScript.Echo("found")
  'objExplorer.quit 
 else
  'Do nothing
  WScript.Echo("not found")
 End if 
 Set objWMIService = Nothing
 Set colProcessList = Nothing
 counter = counter + 1
Loop
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your VB script:

1. Create a file in an folder the PS script can access.
2. Launch your loading image.
3. Launch your PS script.
4. In your wait loop, every second or so, check if the file still exists.
   If it does, close the instance of IE and exit your script.

In your PS script:

1. After your form initialization code is finished or the first action after the form load, locate and delete the file.